# Docker-Compose Failed to register symlink

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I´m trying to run an docker-compose file. But I always get the error message:

> failed to register layer: symlink
> ../118db2348300daaa2443c22d8bd790d2985a25b5e42f49404e9f3b4333e776dd/diff/mnt/usb1/docker/fuse-overlayfs/l/NLEONPNG5QHTMTGHCWRQLIQ2DG: operation not permitted

It has something to do with the storage driver `fuse-overlayfs` which I use because I changed the `data-root` to my external HDD with vfat format.

Any hints?

Edit 1: The docker-compose file in question:

```
prometheus:
  image: ajeetraina/prometheus-armv7
  volumes:
    - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
  command:
    - "-config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
  ports:
    - "9090:9090"

grafana:
  image: fg2it/grafana-armhf:v3.1.1
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

Comment: Please  edit thie question and share the docker-compose.yml file, in the part involved here (symlink or volumes)

Answer (score 0):

The Fat file system does not support symlink, reformatting the HDD to ext4 solved the problem.